# Best Practices Virtual

Tags: c++

Is it best practices to put the `virtual` keyword in the header files of the derived classes?

Here is an example:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void Func();
};
```

Would you derive class B as this:

```
class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual void Func();
};
```

Or this:

```
class B : public A
{
public:
    void Func();
};
```

Comment: It's a matter of taste - brevity versus explicitness. In C++11, I'd write `void Func() override;` to both make the virtualness explicit, and to make sure it is overriding what I think it is.

Comment: If you want to go wild, you could say that if you require runtime polymorphism, then you should only be handling objects via base pointers, and the base should be abstract, and the derived classes should have `private: virtual void Func() override;`.

Answer (score 3):

It's best practice to use the override specifier: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override in C++11 (also in earlier versions of Visual C++ as a Microsoft extension).

If the override is there, then the virtual is redundant, as seen in the linked example above.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, explicitness is typically considered the best practice. The language does specify that the `virtual` specifier is added implicitly if a function *can* be an override, but that's "sneaky."

C++11 also adds the `override` and `final` qualifiers so you can ensure that you're extending the base, not defining an entirely new function.

These qualifiers require a virtual function. They do not imply `virtual` but the implicit `virtual` would have to be there. But again, explicitness is the best policy.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is best to be as explicit as necessary.  If you are overriding a function in a derived class, you should specify it.  If you do not intend that function to be overridden again, make it final.  The declaration is your contract with users of the class.  If you make it clear (and yet still concise), it will be less likely to be used incorrectly.

Comment: No, `B::func` overrides `A::func` here even if you don't explicitly declare it virtual.

Comment: Alas, this is just wishful thinking. Virtual functions cannot be hidden.

Comment: Doh ... typing and not thinking /facepalm.